# Is this a bug in pgf ? pgfpatharcto

Tags: pgf-core, arc

I made a simple and shortest example. I create a simple path containing an arc. But if I compute that path before the begin document, I obtain garbage, whereas it works as expected after begin document. I'm not sure if it's a feature or a bug.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
%% create a simple path containing an arc
\newcommand{\mypath}[1]{\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}%
\pgfpatharcto{1cm}{1cm}{0}{1}{0}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}\pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath{#1}\pgfusepath{}}
%% compute and assign the path to \bugpath
\mypath\bugpath
\begin{document}
%% compute and assign the path to \path
x\mypath\path y% <- why so much space between x and y ?
%% stroke \path
\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{\path}\pgfsyssoftpath@flushcurrentpath\pgfusepath{draw}%
%% stroke \bugpath in red
\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}%
\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{\bugpath}\pgfsyssoftpath@flushcurrentpath\pgfusepath{draw}%
%% stroke a blue rectangle to contain the previous strokes
\tikz{\path[draw=blue] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,5cm);}
\end{document}
```

I would like to understand why the path in red and the path in black are not the same.

Subsidiary question : why so much space between x and y ?

[image: Result of the example]

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what happens there, but as far as I know, fonts are not quite set up before `\begin{document}` and `\normalfont\mypath\bugpath` “fixes” the observed behaviour (in fact, `\normalsize` does too). It may be even safer to do this in a box: `\sbox0{\normalsize\mypath\bugpath\global\let\bugpath\bugpath}`.

Comment: Path commands outside of a `pgfpicture` have no guaranteed behaviour. As p563 of the PGF 2.10 manual suggests: "Give graphic commands only inside {pgfpicture} environments". The spaces shouldn't really be there, but either way: `\nullfont` is used inside a `pgfpicture` to try and make sure spaces don't upset positioning.

Comment: And what @MarkWibrow says. What are you trying to achieve here anyway? You are without doubt missing some `pgfpicture` environments. More about the `pgfpicture` environment can be found in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), subsection 69.3.1 “The Main Environment”, pp. 564ff.

Comment: Ok I just did not realized the pgfpicture was needed, because most of my other uses were working well without pgfpicture ! It's strange that `\normalfont` fixes the problem. Why such a path computation that are not related to any font needs it ???

Comment: Strange as it may seem, drawing commands may use fonts to produce their lines (after all, what other mechanism is there for getting ink onto the page in TeX?  It's either a font or a `\rule`).

Comment: There are drawing capabilities in postscript and pdf that do not depend of any fonts !!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Mind to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not entirely sure what happens there, but as far as I know, fonts are not quite set up before `\begin{document}` and

```
\normalfont\mypath\bugpath
```

“fixes” the observed behaviour (in fact, `\normalsize` does too).

It may be even safer to do this in a box:

```
\sbox0{\normalsize\mypath\bugpath\global\let\bugpath\bugpath}
```

Though, as [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114074/is-this-a-bug-in-pgf-pgfpatharcto?noredirect=1#comment251714_114074) comments, you should put all PGF commands in a `pgfpicture` environment anyway, so you can do

```
\sbox0{\pgfpicture\mypath\bugpath\global\let\bugpath\bugpath\endpgfpicture}
```

in the preamble or in the document.

If you want to save a path for later and/or repeated use, you can also just use `\mypath` again …

Comment: I know this is a filler answer but it's actually PDF driver not understanding the PDF literals and trying it's best. Using `pgfpicture` sets everything properly such that the drawing commands are interpreted properly. OP is wrong on this one as we cannot just start using graphics objects like that without setting up a really large set of preconditions.